# Custom section in pipfile

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

Is it possible to set up a custom section in the pipfile?

By default I see only `[packages]` and `[dev-packages]`, but I have extra dependencies for some environment. So I want to install `packages` and for example `[tests]` but not `[dev-packages]`.

E.G.:

```
pipenv install --tests
# or 
pipenv install --my-custom-section
```

Before that I used `requirements.txt`, `requirements-dev.txt`, `requirements-integration.txt`. Is there any good way to implement it with `pipenv`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Let's look into documentation

If we look in [Pipfile. The Concept](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/blob/master/README.rst#the-concept):

> Pipfile will be superior to requirements.txt file in a number of ways:
>   ...
>
> - Existing requirements files tend to proliferate into multiple files - e.g. dev-requirements.txt, test-requirements.txt, etc. - but a Pipfile **will allow seamlessly specifying groups of dependencies** in one place. * This will be surfaced as only two built-in groups (default & development). (see **note** below)
>
> ### Note
>
> Custom groups **may be added in the future**. Remember, it is easier to add features in the future than it is to remove them. The Composer community has been successful with only default and development as group options for many years. This model is being followed.

## Answer

It's not possible now although it was designed with idea of such possibility.

Maybe it will be possible in future.

Comment: nice explanation bro plus 1

Answer (score 1):

#### The Good News:

Just to give an update to someone else who comes here later. The feature to add categories to pip has been implemented to pipenv.

It was discussed in [this](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4745) issue and was implement in this [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/5366).

#### How it works?

If you want to install a package in a specific category in your pipfile, you can do the following:

`pipenv install fastapi --categories api`

This will add a new category called `api` in your Pipfie.

Later if you want to install the packages from your category only you can do:

`pip install --categories=api`

It also supports synchronization of categories and locks.

```
pipenv sync --categories="prereq packages"
```

For uninstallation:

```
 pipenv lock --categories="prereq dev-packages"
 pipenv uninstall six --categories prereq
```

#### Learn More:

[Here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/4fa70dba6828bfef60498a0de251e50d89885eeb/docs/basics.rst#-specifying-package-categories) ..